# How to get Correlation using Options data?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, beta, capm

I can calculate the "Implied Beta" using implied volatility for the option stock, and implied volatility for the market (VIX). 
Is there any way to calculate also the correlation without performing a statistical analysis on historical data.

$\beta = ({\rho \sigma_{aapl}\ \sigma_{sp500}})/{\sigma_{sp500}} $

I know about the ["Implied correlation"](https://www.cboe.com/micro/impliedcorrelation/) but this is the **average correlation** for all the stocks with the S&P500. I would the correlation for that particular stock

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no. You need historical data to backuo the implied correlation.

A smart way to do it is to use Buss and Vilkov (2009) methodology.

Denote the risk-neutral correlation between each pair of stocks: $\rho_{ij,t}^Q$. The presence of the correlation premia led Buss and Vilkov (2009) to estimate the risk-neutral correlation by making:
\begin{equation}
\rho_{ij,t}^Q=\rho_{ij,t}^P-\alpha_t(1-\rho_{ij,t}^P)
\end{equation}

Combining the above equation with the identifying restriction that equates the the observed implied variance of the market index $(\sigma_{i,t}^Q)^2$ with the calculated implied variance of a portfolio of all market index constituents $i =1,...,N$:
\begin{equation}
(\sigma_{i,t}^Q)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}w_iw_j\sigma^Q_{i,t}\sigma^Q_{j,t}\rho^Q_{ij,t}
\end{equation}
one can solve for $\alpha$ and consequently get $\rho_{ij,t}^Q$.